# Select elements with truncated text due to overflow

Tags: jquery-selectors, overflow

Is there a way to select elements that have text that is truncated due to the CSS `overflow` `text-overflow: ellipsis;` settings?

```
<div>
    <span>Text 1</span><br>
    <span>Text 2</span><br>
    <span>Text Item Trunca...</span>  <-- Select this?
</div>
```

The purpose would be for selecting items that are truncated in order to display the entire text in something like a Bootstrap tooltip:

```
$("div span:hidden?").tooltip();
```

Comment: the above code is your rendered html or input html....?

Comment: The above code is merely a pseudocode example.